# How to position the caption of the figure in the itemize environment?

Tags: floats, itemize, center

I am trying to insert a caption for a figure which is placed inside the itemize environment. Unfortunately, the caption will move to the middle of the document instead of the middle of the itemize environment. Does anyone know, how to change the position of the caption?

This is my code so far:

```
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item ddvd
\begin{center}
     \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{Zero_Crossing_REAL_Abweichung.png}\label{fig:Zero_Crossing}
     \captionof{figure}[Evaluation der parametrischen Methoden]{Evaluation parametrischen Methoden\label{fig:Eval_Zero}}
    \end{center}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I would put the caption (and image) inside a minipage {\linewidth}.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For several reasons (not least avoiding a page break between the image and the caption) it is best to place non floating figures in a `minipage` then centering is easy to achieve.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{capt-of}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item ddvd
\begin{center}
     \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image}%\label{fig:Zero_Crossing}no
     \captionof{figure}[Evaluation der parametrischen Methoden]{Evaluation parametrischen Methoden\label{fig:Eval_Zero}}
    \end{center}
 \noindent X\dotfill X


\item ddvd

\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}\centering
     \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image}
     \captionof{figure}[Evaluation der parametrischen Methoden]{Evaluation parametrischen Methoden\label{fig:2Eval_Zero}}
    \end{minipage}

 \noindent X\dotfill X
\end{itemize}

 \noindent X\dotfill X

\end{document}
```

(please post full documents not fragments)

Answer (score 0):

You can play with the `margin` key of `caption`:

```
\documentclass[preview]{article}%
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} 
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item ddvd
\begin{center}
\captionsetup{margin ={\leftmargini, 0pt}} \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{Zero_Crossing_REAL_Abweichung.png}\label{fig:Zero_Crossing}
     \captionof{figure}[Evaluation der parametrischen Methoden]{Evaluation parametrischen Methoden\label{fig:Eval_Zero}}
    \end{center}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]